# Solution of a matrix differential system which verifies $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \lVert A(t) \rVert dt < \infty$ admit a finite limit over $+\infty$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Let be $A : \mathbb{R}_{+} \to M_n(\mathbb{R})$ a continuous function such that:

\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{+\infty} \lVert A(t) \rVert dt < \infty
\end{equation*}

Let be $u$ a solution to the following differential equation $u'(t) = A(t) u(t)$

How to show that $u$ must have a finite limit at $+\infty$ ?

As we are over a finite dimensional space, I can pick any matrix norm.

I tried to start from:

\begin{align*}
\lVert u(t) - u(0) \rVert & = \left \lVert \int_0^t u'(x) dx \right \rVert \\
& = \left \lVert \int_0^t A(x) u(x) dx \right \rVert \\
& \leq \int_0^t \lVert A(x) u(x) \rVert dx \\
& \leq \int_0^t \lVert A(x) \rVert \lVert u(x) \rVert dx \\
\end{align*}

If I can show that $u$ is bounded by $M$, then, I'll have:

\begin{equation*}
\lVert u(t) \rVert \leq \lVert u(0) \rVert + M\int_0^{t} \lVert A(x) \rVert dx
\end{equation*}

And then, when $t \to +\infty$, by the hypothesis, I have the result.

But now, it feels like that showing $u$ is bounded is somehow equivalent to showing that $u$ has a finite limit over $+\infty$.

Comment: Do you know this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grönwall%27s_inequality

Comment: @Mindlack Yes, but I'm unsure on how to use it here?

Comment: Use the (b) in the integral form, $\beta=\|A\|$, $u_{Wiki}=\|u_{yours}\|$.

Comment: Yes… Thank you, I got it @Mindlack now ; should I remove my question/answer to it?

Comment: Whichever suits you better, I would guess. If this is not a duplicate, this may ne interesting to keep.